# Proof that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + x^2}} - \frac{x^2}{(x^2 + 1)^{3/2}} = \frac{1}{(x^2+1)^{3/2}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals, fractions

Solving the equality

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + x^2}} - \frac{x^2}{(x^2 + 1)^{3/2}} = \frac{1}{(x^2+1)^{3/2}}$$

could help to defined the proof for the question 1.3 of the book [Neural Networks by Simon S. Haykin](https://books.google.com.br/books/about/Neural_Networks.html?id=bX4pAQAAMAAJ&source=kp_book_description&redir_esc=y) (a simplified text).

> Let
>
> $$\sigma(v) = \frac{v}{\sqrt(1 + v^2)}$$
>
> show that the derivative of $\sigma(v)$ is given by
>
> $$\frac{d\sigma}{dv} = \frac{\sigma^3(v)}{v^3}$$

I wrote an alternative resolution for that question in this post, but another insights and approaches could help to improve the final anwser.

Comment: $$\dfrac1{\sqrt{1+x^2}}=\dfrac{1+x^2}{(1+x^2)^{3/2}}$$ right?

Comment: Your question received several close votes - probably it might be useful if you explicitly mention directly in the question that you have also posted your own answer. (I certainly appreciate that you posted an answer and went through the effort of solving the problem yourself and also posted the solution here.) I will add a link to [How to ask a good question.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) - in particular the part [about context](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960) is relevant for this question.

Comment: Thank you for you feedback, Martin Sleziak. I am updating my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}-\dfrac{x^2}{{(1+x^2)}^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$
Let,$$p=\sqrt{1+x^2}$$
So,we get
$$
\begin{array}
 \\L.H.S&=&\\
 &=& \dfrac{1}{p}-\dfrac{x^2}{p^3}\\
 &=& \dfrac{p^2-x^2}{p^3}\\
 &=& \dfrac{1+x^2-x^2}{{(1+x^2)}^{\frac{3}{2}}}\\
 &=& \dfrac{1}{{(1+x^2)}^{\frac{3}{2}}}=R.H.S_{[proved]}\\
\end{array}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1 + x^2}} = \dfrac{1}{(1 + x^2)^{1/2}} = \dfrac{1+x^2}{(1+x^2)(1 + x^2)^{1/2}} = \dfrac{1+x^2}{(1 + x^2)^{3/2}}$$

Answer (score 0):

It suffices simplify algebrically for example by $1+x^2=y$ we have

$$\frac1{\sqrt y}-\frac{y-1}{y\sqrt{y}}=\frac{\sqrt y}y-\frac{(y-1)\sqrt y}{y^2}=\frac{y\sqrt y-y\sqrt y+\sqrt y}{y^2}=\ldots$$

or as a tricky alternative just use $x=\sinh y \implies 1+x^2=\cosh^2 y$ to obtain

$$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1 + x^2}} - \dfrac{x^2}{(x^2 + 1)^{3/2}} = \dfrac{1}{(x^2+1)^{3/2}}$$

$$\dfrac{1}{\cosh y} - \dfrac{\sinh^2y}{\cosh^3 y} = \dfrac{1}{\cosh^3 y}$$

$$\dfrac{\cosh^2 y-\sinh^2 y}{\cosh^3 y} = \dfrac{1}{\cosh^3 y}$$
$$\dfrac{1}{\cosh^3 y} = \dfrac{1}{\cosh^3 y}$$

Answer (score 0):

I solved that problem using factorization multiplying the left part by $\frac{(1 + x^2)}{(1 + x^2)}$.

$$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt(1 + x^2)} - \dfrac{x^2}{(1 + x^2)^{3/2}}$$

$$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt(1 + x^2)} \times \dfrac{1 + x^2}{1 + x^2} - \dfrac{x^2}{(1 + x^2)^{3/2}}$$

$$\dfrac{1 + x^2}{(1 + x^2)^{1/2} \times (1 + x^2)^{1}} - \dfrac{x^2}{(1 + x^2)^{3/2}}$$

$$\dfrac{1 + x^2}{(1 + x^2)^{3/2}} - \dfrac{x^2}{(1 + x^2)^{3/2}}$$

$$\dfrac{1 + x^2 - x^2}{(1 + x^2)^{3/2}}$$

$$\dfrac{1}{(1 + x^2)^{3/2}}$$